# Error 101 when calling service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm totally new on Symfony so I followed a tutorial and I'm now looking for an answer to my problem.

I created a service. But when I call it in my controller, Chrome says : ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
When I remove the line that calls it, it works without any problem.

**Here's my code in the controller :**

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        $listAdverts = $this->$container->get('databaseinfos.listannonces'); /*DOES NOT WORK*/ 
return $this->render('CoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('listAdverts'=>$listAdv‌​erts)); 
    }

}
```

**The code of my services.yml file :**

```
services:
    databaseinfos.listannonces:
        class: CoreBundle\DatabaseInfos
```

**And the code of my service :**

```
<?php

    namespace CoreBundle\DatabaseInfos;

    class DatabaseInfos
    {
        public function getList(){
            // Notre liste d'annonce en dur
            $listAdverts = array(
            array(
            'title'   => 'Recherche développpeur Symfony',
            'id'      => 1,
            'author'  => 'Alexandre',
            'content' => 'Nous recherchons un développeur Symfony débutant sur Lyon. Blabla…',
            'date'    => new \Datetime()),
            array(
            'title'   => 'Mission de webmaster',
            'id'      => 2,
            'author'  => 'Hugo',
            'content' => 'Nous recherchons un webmaster capable de maintenir notre site internet. Blabla…',
            'date'    => new \Datetime()),
            array(
            'title'   => 'Offre de stage webdesigner',
            'id'      => 3,
            'author'  => 'Mathieu',
            'content' => 'Nous proposons un poste pour webdesigner. Blabla…',
            'date'    => new \Datetime())
            );

            return $listAdverts;
        }
    }
```

**Here the template called by the controller :**

```
{% extends "CoreBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
  Accueil principale - {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Page d'accueil du super site d'annonces !</h1>
<ul>
    {% for advert in listAdverts %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ path('oc_platform_view', {'id': advert.id}) }}">
          {{ advert.title }}
        </a>
        par {{ advert.author }},
        le {{ advert.date|date('d/m/Y') }}
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li>Pas (encore !) d'annonces</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your time and answers !
Have a good day =)

Comment: Well if you've tracked down the line of code which causes the problem, why not share it along with some additional code that would also help us understand what's going on? We're not psychic here.

Comment: Added the code in the question, thank you ^^

Comment: That seems ok, is there any redirects going on in the rendered template? Anything that may cause this to go in an infinite loop?

Comment: I just added the code that is in my template but it seems like it's not doing an infinite loop :l

Comment: Hmm, not a symphony expert, but you're using `extends "CoreBundle::layout.html.twig"`  shouldn't it be `CoreBundle:layout.html.twig` ?

Comment: No, it is "::" because I call the folder "views" without entering in another folder that is inside.
The "layout.html.twig" file is just in the "views" folder ^^

Comment: Would `$listAdverts = $this->get('databaseinfos.listannonces')->getList()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why it didn't work:

I declared in my `services.yml` :

```
services:
    databaseinfos.listannonces:
        class: CoreBundle\DatabaseInfos
```

But the `DatabaseInfos.php` file is in `CoreBundle/DatabaseInfos/DatabaseInfos.php`

So the services.yml file should be like this :

```
services:
    databaseinfos.listannonces:
        class: CoreBundle\DatabaseInfos\DatabaseInfos
```

And the command to get the list (the method `getList()` of the class in DatabaseInfos.php) is : `$this->container->get('databaseinfos')->getList()`